# Line spacing in \tiny parallel footnotes

Tags: spacing, footnotes, line-spacing, setspace

I'm using parallel footnotes in my document.  Out of the box, it looks great:[image: Footnote-sized footnotes, regular spacing]
However, I want to reduce the footnote size to `\tiny`.  Easy enough with this command: `\renewcommand\footnotesize{\tiny}`

When I do this, the footnotes do indeed appear tiny, but the line spacing (line-height?) is retained from `\footnotesize`, making them look double spaced, and failing to achieve the intended spacing savings.  See: [image: Excess spacing in footnotes]

I have experimented with no luck in trying to use the `setspace` package to apply just to the footnotes region.  Also, I would like to avoid having to inject something into each footnote, preferring to define something upfront and have it apply globally.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a5paper,6pt]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[para,hang]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\section{Regular Footnotes, Regular Spacing}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{Small footnote 1}
\lipsum[2] \footnote{Small footnote 2} 
\lipsum[3]\footnote{Small footnote 3}  
\lipsum[4]\footnote{Long footnote: \lipsum[5]}  

\newpage
\renewcommand\footnotesize{\tiny\par}%How to make the line height/spacing \tiny as well?
\section{Small Footnotes, but Regular Spacing}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{Small footnote 1}
\lipsum[2] \footnote{Small footnote 2} 
\lipsum[3]\footnote{Small footnote 1}  
\lipsum[4]\footnote{Long footnote \lipsum[5]\par}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting and copying the externally stored material into the body of the query.

Comment: Off-topic: the document class option `6pt` has no effect when used with the `book` document class. The only fontsize-related options that the `article`, `report`, and `book` classes know about are `10pt` (the default), `11pt`, and `12pt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `footmisc` introduces the `\footnotebaselineskip` and sets it to the baselineskip in `\footnotesize`. Also `\footnotesep` should be changed.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[para,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\footnotesize}{\tiny}{}{}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\tiny
  \global\footnotesep=0.7\baselineskip
  \global\footnotebaselineskip\baselineskip
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}

\section{Regular Footnotes, Regular Spacing}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{Small footnote 1}
\lipsum[2] \footnote{Small footnote 2}
\lipsum[3]\footnote{Small footnote 3}
\lipsum[4]\footnote{Long footnote: \lipsum[5]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I recommend `newpxtext` rather than `palatino`.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you!